# http response regarding content-type

Tags: web, http-headers, webserver

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type:text/html

<html><body><img src=\"http://localhost:5000/twitter.png\" alt=\"Smiley face\" height=\"256\" width=\"256\"/></body></html>
```

Here in this http response example if I change

```
Content-Type:image/*
```

Everything else is just the same. Then what kind of difference does it make ?
When I tested with my simple test web server which I wrote:

In the first case - the exact html was being received by the browser, but the image was not getting displayed. A small image with a triangle, circle embedded in a rectangle was coming.

In the second case with content-type: image/* 
the image requested was getting downloaded but image could not be opened.

For example if

```
Content-Type = image/png
```

the image was not getting downloaded but html perceived by browser was getting changed like

```
 <html>
 <body style="margin: 0px;">
 <img style="-web-user-select: none" src="http://localhost:5000"/>
 </body>
 </html>
```

My question is how to use these content types?

---

Http Response:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type:image/png
 Content-Lenth:27892
 Server:Learnee

 \211PNG

g9\357ax\257a>\307\365\333\324\3658\313
\234H\245\374\215\321\371\373\317\302Rh \364\263K\353\273\362\312+\243\200\\321\376\217\337\360u)\373X\355q*1\267\235\342;I\316\341\265\310\317I:q\332\325\317{0\245T\334^WH#l  s\200\231\2422\252q>;\346\312d\252X\201\365\312\304%:\216H\316\306\372{\323axDB\215\3178Y\345\254*\245\366R\357a\235    җ\2148\252D\236S\232\231\370z\342w\337\375V\265Z\315c/:,d\311<շ\367D1\356\337\326֖\373\242\263t\351\325\377IRmo\264R\376S\200\352_\276\242K7\214\263\333{\230\267횥\313qc\317\347S\3022<ه\202\273ڟ\203l\310\344\216\356M\322Я\225\240\300=N1\277\271\355\327ߺtv̀ٙ\231\231\374\226-[\204~\265U\341\220OO\344\211q\316\257\246\276\345&\354\352\227\325!\274<\264\233\234\352p\263\301\3237\275\334و\203]\2712\371\332\306I\222\207\233\341獶\215\257&7Y7 K\302u@\373\235\370   0\275\373ؾ$\235B$z?\200zD\343yǯܓ\356\241BW\327\320m\214\337\301f\327@\300a\201\262C\257\244\216p\366\330\220\325\301@\215\332G/-\320Ԃ\267\246X%\344ȔD\216N{\277Q\277\3361M\276\264~/i\213\3529D\320@`\307\314N@=\334\316\200\272\300)\367}?<L\233D\372\227\275-[$\375\330.\222\257T\351\313em\377\263q]:\307@p%Xӭ\204\222\365>8K\266ga\200@
H3\352Z3\200R\320\347SU\301
G>\323!\307tD\200\205{~\370\3524\371鶌>S\220\263D5\224(@\214SN\221{\264L@f\216%\247\200  \360\3455\376Y`\341s\263U2YR\214p\363\320pA[?\237A\270@\357\214\221\273x!\240*\327o\231"\367\215\314\325&E\321Su \220)\200\243\261\363@\200\335a\265\337.\242~Y\300\242d\214f\232\262\231\275E\370㣫W\257\216%\223\3114(~
+=\261\347EP|\264\377G\200L\213řB\241\220۴iS\371\251\247\236r\360OD\231\371G\376a\354tt
\364~6\217\3471\364'
```

Code for fetching data from file:

```
bool ServerFileSystem::getDataFromFile(std::string urlPath, std::string& chunkData)
{
std::stringstream stream;
std::cout << urlPath << std::endl;

if(!strcmp(urlPath.c_str(), "/"))
{
    urlPath = urlPath + "index.html";
    std::cout << "URL Path: " << urlPath;
}

std::string localPath = SERVER_ROOT + urlPath;
std::ifstream file(localPath.c_str());

file.seekg(0, std::ifstream::beg);

while(file.tellg() != -1)
{
    char *p = new char[1024];

    bzero(p, 1024);
    file.read(p, 1024);

    stream << p;
    stream.flush();

    delete p;
}

chunkData = stream.str();

file.close();

return true;
}
```

I am getting the whole data in the form of string and appending headers necessary. So, the final response which I am sending is the one shown above the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type:text/html

<html>[...]</html>
```

> If I change [the Content-Type-header] to `Content-Type:image/*`, everything else is just the same. Then what kind of difference does it make ?

You're in luck: your browser adheres to the robustness principle. It could say: *"I don't know what you're trying to do, but I'm not going to render HTML as an image. I think I'll just issue a "Cannot display page" error"*.

Instead it goes: *"Wait, the content does look like HTML, why not give it a try?"*.

You will want to serve your HTML as such, and the same goes for images: serve them with the appropriate image MIME type.

See also:

> [RFC 2045, section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-5):

> The purpose of the Content-Type field is to describe the data
> contained in the body fully enough that **the receiving user agent can
> pick an appropriate agent or mechanism to present the data to the
> user**, or otherwise deal with the data in an appropriate manner. The
> value in this field is called a media type.

Comment: I am trying to display an image on browser by sending its through the socket upon receiving the request. So, now for that I am reading the image (let it be "imagedat" in string). For that i m creating http response like <html><body> "imagedat" </body> </html> of course with needed headers. But the image is not getting displayed on the browser. Am I doing that correctly ?

Comment: @Chaitanya no. Why would you embed image data in HTML tags? Simply send headers indicating an image is coming, then read the file and directly transmit its contents, without altering them.

Comment: Ok. I did as you said, but still the image is not getting displayed on the browser. I am populating the image data in a string and appending it to the headers and then sending the response. Am I correct ?

Comment: @Chaitanya that could be correct, depending on what the response looks like. Please update your question with a dump from [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp), for example, but first try to see for yourself what is wrong with the response, perhaps by comparing it with a working response from a public web site. Also show the code you use to read the image file and write it to the socket.

Comment: @Chaitanya I think you should write a byte array, not a string.

Comment: U mean to say i should take a char * right? Another doubt is like can I send the data at a single stretch or do I need to send in the form of chunks ?

Comment: @Chaitanya I have barely any C++ experience, don't know what data type is appropriate. If a `char` stores one byte and (the method used to read the data) doesn't do unicode magic, you're good to go. You must send the data as-is. And no, no need for chunking, take a look at the appropriate RFC's if you want to implement that.

Comment: thanks for helping me out. Now I could get a better idea. Thanks a ton. :)